# Showing two metrics are equivalent iff bases are equivalent.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let d<sub>1</sub> and d<sub>2</sub> be metrics for a set X, and let B<sub>1</sub> and B<sub>2</sub> denote, respectively, the families of all open balls generated by d<sub>1</sub> and d<sub>2</sub>. Show that d<sub>1</sub> and d<sub>2</sub> are equivalent metrics iff B<sub>1</sub> and B<sub>2</sub> are equivalent bases.

Comment: Usually, posts with just the question are not taken well in this website. Try to write what you understand of the problem, which definitions confuse you, and attempts! After this, I'm sure we will help you!

Comment: Start by writing out the *definition* of "equivalent metrics" and the *definition* of "equivalent bases" and comparing the two.